# Mutual piping on linux

Tags: linux, pipe

I would like the output of `A` to be input for `B` and at the same time the output of `B` to be the input for `A`, is that possible?

I tried the naïve thing: creating named pipes for `A` (`pipeA`) and `B` (`pipeB`) and then:

```
pipeB | A | pipeA &
pipeA | B | pipeB &
```

But that does not work (`pipeB` is empty and switching the order would not help either).

Any help would be appreciated.

Example:

Command `A` could be compiled form of this C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("0\n");

    int x = 0;
    while (scanf("%d", &x) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%d\n", x + 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Command `B` could be compiled form of this C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{    
    int x = 0;
    while (scanf("%d", &x) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%d\n", x + x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like the output of A to be input for B and at the same time
>   the output of B to be the input for A, is that possible?

I don't see how this could possibly work.

If both processes **depend on each other** to generate output, process B will wait until process A produces some output, but process A won't generate any output until it gets input from process B.

Both processes would block forever.

**EDIT**:

The OP has commented below a different case in which a process A generates some output and then waits for input for process B, while process B simply waits for process A.

**In this case we can get "mutual piping" to work.** Create two scripts:

`/tmp/multualpipingA` (this script generates some output with `echo process A` and waits):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo process A
while read; do
    echo process A says: \"$REPLY\"
    sleep 1
done < /dev/stdin
```

and `/tmp/multualpipingB` (this script only reacts to input):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read; do
    echo process B says: \"$REPLY\"
    sleep 1
done < /dev/stdin
```

Now open two terminal sessions, "1" and "2" and type in this order:

> `session1$ mkfifo /tmp/fifo{A,B}`
>
> `session1$ cat /tmp/fifoB | /tmp/multualpipingB | tee /tmp/fifoA` <kbd>Enter</kbd>
>
> `session2$ cat /tmp/fifoA | /tmp/multualpipingA | tee /tmp/fifoB` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

You will see this ouput:

```
process A
process A says: "process B says: "process A""
process A says: "process B says: "process A says: "process B says: "process A""""
```

and this:

```
process B says: "process A"
process B says: "process A says: "process B says: "process A"""
process B says: "process A says: "process B says: "process A says: "process B says: "process A"""""
```

(tested on OS X 10.8.2 "Montain Lion")

Comment: In general case, yes, they could block forever. But consider the case where: 1. A writes; 2. B reads and reacts (writes); 3. A reads what B has written and writes again, etc.

Comment: Yes, the case you describe would definitely work. I've updated my answer with a (hopefully) illustrative example.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this if you have [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
command | tee >(command1) | tee >(command2)
```

It's named *Process Substitution*

Real life©®™ example :

```
$ echo foobar | tee >(grep -o "f") | tee >(grep -o "r")
foobar
r
f
$
```

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution or http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024 for a common use.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'm not quite sure what `command` should be. I guess `command1` is `A` and `command2` is `B`.

Comment: I have added example of what `A` and `B` might be to my question.

Comment: Too specific since your edit. Added a real life example in my post

Comment: It's no more specific than it was, I have just added an example.